# Creating a skeleton for a Game Algorithm in Android

Tags: android, view, android-activity, runnable

I need some help on the following:

1. I have the following class:

public class Game extends Activity {...

...}

2. My questions is:

   - Where and how do I create my View (do I use another class that extends View....)
   - Where and how do I implement the Runnable interface so I would be able to use threads.
   - Where and how do I connect all three (the Activity, the View, the Run() method)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a simple Android "hello world!" app first to get the hang of the framework. That will answer your first question.

Then, you should probably start developing your game by reading [this](http://www.gleisarbeiter.de/2009/06/01/developing-an-android-mobile-game-part-1/) and looking at the `SurfaceView` or OpenGL docs on [d.android.com](http://d.android.com)

Comment: Unfortunately, I found only SurcafeView a bit useful. However, Im not a novice, and ive done some apps. I guess im so stressed out that i can not even post my questions right. But, tnx for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the most basic algorithm not just for Android games but any game at all, 
if your serious about developing games the I'd suggest you better get reading. theres lot of cool stuff out there that can help you on your way.

http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html

http://androidforums.com/application-development/34966-android-game-development-tutorial.html

http://www.anddev.org/viewforum.php?f=2

http://www.quesucede.com/page/show/id/conway_game_of_life_android

These are just a few links that can help you understand android game development. google for more, im sure you'll find what your looking for